# Почему используя ConfigureAwait(true) мы оставляеем потенциальную дыру для дедлоков?

Tags: c#, async-await

Не понимаю почему `ConfigureAwait(true)` может быть причиной беды?

Вот пример кода:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int result = DoSomeWorkAsync().Result; // 1
}

private async Task<int> DoSomeWorkAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(true); //2
    return 1;
}
```

Вот его описание, но то ли тут опечатка/кривой [перевод](https://habr.com/post/257221/) или я чего то не понимаю. Почему дедлок?:

Клик по кнопке здесь приводит к дедлоку. UI поток стартует новый I/O поток на строке «2» и уходит в спящий режим на строке «1», ожидая завершения работы. После того как I/O поток заканчивает выполнение, оставшаяся часть метода DoSomeWorkAsync передается на выполнение вызывающему (UI) потоку. Но тот в это время находится в спящем режиме, ожидая завершения метода. Дедлок.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Лично я обьяснение @tym32167 не понял. Пришлось самому запускать апликуху и вкуривать что случается...

Итак...

---

Асинхронный вызов метода:

```
int result = await DoSomeWorkAsync();
```

Синхронный вызов асинхронного метода:

```
int result = DoSomeWorkAsync().Result; 
// то есть мы ждем пока не будет
// готового результата
```

---

Теперь смотрим на нутрянку метода DoSomeWorkAsync():

```
await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(true);
return 1;
```

.ConfigureAwait(true) -- конфигурация самой таски. Конфигурирование таски делается из UI потока, а не изнутри самой таски.

Дэдлок выходит по той причине, что перед компьютером поставлено одновременно 2 противоречивые задачи:

- **не выходить в основной поток** *[что бы получить результат выполнения синхронного вызова метода]*
- *(внутри метода)* **выйти в основой поток** *[что бы изменить конфигурацию таски]*

Comment: @tym32167 - прости что написал +- то же самое что и ты... просто я тебя не вкурил вооще.... А значит и он не вкурил бы, скорее всего....

Comment: А что в моем ответе вызвало у вас трудности? Вы же описали ровно то же самое, что и я.

Comment: :) никаких проблем, пусть у автора вопроса будет выбор, два ответа лучше, чем один

Comment: когда я прочитал ответ - я просто не понял что конкретно там написано. Перечитал еще раз -- все равно не понял. До меня дошло что там написано только после того как сам поигрался с кодом в вижуалке) Поэтому решил расписать отдельно то же самое. Думаю здесь вопрос не неправильности твоего ответа как такового... Просто недостаточно понятная формулировка обьяснения :) По крайней мере для меня лично. А править твой ответ моими словами просто не решился -- неправильно это как-то.

Comment: Ага, наверное, надо было подробней расписать, спасибо, учту на будущее.

Comment: @tym32167, у вас не указано почему "Так вот, таске, чтобы завершиться, надо прыгнуть в UI поток". А в этом ответе, про это уже немного сказано. Хотя мне всё равно не до конца понятно, но это только потому что я ещё не прочитал\перечитал документацию `.ConfigureAwait()`

Comment: Оба ответа правильные :) вообще await чаще скрытое зло, лучше явно использовать Task, как по мне. Вариантов контроля намного больше.

Answer (score 7):

Потому, что вызов

```
int result = DoSomeWorkAsync().Result; // 1
```

Заблокирует UI поток, пока таска, что внутри, полностью не завершится. А таске, чтобы завершиться вот тут

```
await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(true); //2
return 1; // вот тут, в продолжении
```

Так вот, таске, чтобы завершиться, надо прыгнуть в UI поток, но она не может прыгнуть в UI поток, так как UI поток ей же самой заблокирован выше.

То есть продолжение таски ждет, когда таска закончится, а таске, чтобы закончится, надо выполнить продолжение. На лицо дедлок.